# React.js: How to render separated jsx modules from one app.jsx file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

Hi i made different and separated react .jsx modules (files) and i want to call them and render from a single file called app.jsx.

This is one of the modules:

```
    var React = require('react'),
    mui = require('material-ui'),
    DatePicker = mui.DatePicker;

var DatePicker = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (

            <div className="DatePicker">
                <DatePicker hintText="Elige una fecha" mode="landscape" />     
            </div>
        );
    },
});

module.exports = DatePicker;
```

This is the app.jsx file where i want to launch the render of the separated modules:

```
(function () {
  var React = require('react'),
    injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin"),
    Main = require('./components/main.jsx'); // Our custom react component
    DatePicker = require('./components/DatePicker.jsx'); 

  //Needed for React Developer Tools
  window.React = React;

  //Needed for onTouchTap
  //Can go away when react 1.0 release
  injectTapEventPlugin();

  React.render(<Main />, document.body);
  React.render(<DatePicker />, document.getElementById('DatePicker'));    

})();
```

The Main component is rendering but not the DatePicker, is this the correct method to render multiple separated components or i have to change my mind and build the application in a different way?

Regards,
Javier

Comment: do you have an element with `id="DatePicker"` somewhere? if not, you need to create one, or just add it to the Main component instead of rendering it separately

Comment: @AustinGreco Hi, i have that var DatePicker with the component of material ui, im wondering if the `DatePicker = require('./components/DatePicker.jsx');` takes the DatePicker element into app.jsx and render from there. Im a bit lost, im looking how material ui website was made on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing issues:

```
React.render(<Main />, document.body);
```

This will replace the content of the `<body>` tag with a React.js component. It's why the following line isn't working:

```
React.render(<DatePicker />, document.getElementById('DatePicker'));
```

The `<div id='DatePicker' />` was replaced by your `<Main />` component.

So you have to either do the following:

```
<body>
   <div id='Main'></div>
   <div id='DatePicker'></div>
</body>

React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('Main'));
React.render(<DatePicker />, document.getElementById('DatePicker'));
```

Or let the `<Main />` component render the `<DatePicker />` component.

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <div><DatePicker /></div>;
  }
});
```